# Snakemake: Singularity parameters --home and --bind set by default but disallowed on HPC

Tags: hpc, snakemake, singularity-container

I have already posted this as an issue on Github at https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/279 but haven't got any response yet. I hope to find help here.

**Version**

I am using the following versions on our HPC cluster:
Snakemake c5.4.4 
singularity version 3.5.3

**Minimal example**

```
singularity: "docker://bash"

rule test:
    shell: "echo test"
```

**Describe the bug**

```
snakemake --use-singularity --debug
```

returns this message:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
Pulling singularity image docker://bash.
Using shell: /bin/bash
Provided cores: 1
Rules claiming more threads will be scaled down.
Job counts:
    count   jobs
    1   test
    1

[Fri Mar 13 15:59:30 2020]
rule test:
    jobid: 0

Activating singularity image /data/nanopore/test/.snakemake/singularity/36b22e49e8a03fd08160e9345dd1034e.simg
FATAL:   container creation failed: not mounting user requested home: user bind control is disallowed
[Fri Mar 13 15:59:30 2020]
Error in rule test:
    jobid: 0

RuleException:
CalledProcessError in line 4 of /data/nanopore/test/Snakefile:
Command ' singularity exec --home /data/nanopore/test  --bind /opt/snakemake/v5.4.4/lib/python3.5/site-packages/snakemake-5.4.4-py3.5.egg:/mnt/snakemake /data/nanopore/test/.snakemake/singularity/36b22e49e8a03fd08160e9345dd1034e.simg bash -c 'set -euo pipefail;  echo test'' returned non-zero exit status 255
  File "/data/nanopore/test/Snakefile", line 4, in __rule_test
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 55, in run
Shutting down, this might take some time.
Exiting because a job execution failed. Look above for error message
Complete log: /data/nanopore/test/.snakemake/log/2020-03-13T155917.601627.snakemake.log
```

Apparently, snakemake runs singularity with default values for --home and --bind. These were disallowed by the administrator, however.

Executing

```
singularity exec --home /data/nanopore/test  --bind /opt/snakemake/v5.4.4/lib/python3.5/site-packages/snakemake-5.4.4-py3.5.egg:/mnt/snakemake /data/nanopore/test/.snakemake/singularity/36b22e49e8a03fd08160e9345dd1034e.simg bash -c 'set -euo pipefail;'
```

returns:

```
FATAL:   container creation failed: not mounting user requested home: user bind control is disallowed
```

**Additional context**
**Is there a way to disable the Singularity default parameter setting in snakemake?** Inside the singularity container the `/data` directory is still writeable and readable anyway.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you run the singularity command outside of snakemake successfully? That is, without binding any snakemake-specific args?

Comment: @ManavalanGajapathy: for example this works: rule test:
    shell: "singularity exec image <image.simg> echo test"

Comment: Does the same singularity command fail when used with snakemake?